# asp:TextBox in ASP Repeater not rebinding after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have an ASP Textbox inside an ASP repeater that binds correctly on the first page paint.  When the user hits Save, the contents are sent to the DB and saved properly, however the DB has logic that changes the value.  I requery the data and have examined the view model being sent back the page and it contains the proper data.  HOwever, when the page finishes updating the data display is what the user entered, not the db modified value that was sent from the code behind to the front end.

I've tried specifically calling DataBind on the repeater, as well as page.DataBind().  I also added a RowDataBind method and specifically updated the value of the text box but it is still displaying the cached value, not the value from the DB.

How do I rebind the text box?  Keep in mind this works on the first page paint, but does not bind to the new data after the postback and repaint.

This is how it's bound on the page:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  placeholder="Account1, Account2"  name="RolldownTxt" id="RolldownTxt" style="height: 12px;width: 98%" 
maxlength="255" class="ExpandableTextBlock" Text='<%# Eval("Rolldown") %>'
onfocus="RolldownTextBoxFocus(this)" onblur="RolldownTextBoxBlur(this)"  onkeyup="RolldownTextBoxFocus(this)"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

and in the code behind

```
    Protected sub NewAccountRepeaterRowDataBind(sender As Object, e as RepeaterItemEventArgs)

    if e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem
        dim rowVm = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, NewAccountRowViewModel)

        dim ctrl = e.item.FindControl("RolldownTxt")
        if ctrl IsNot nothing
            dim txtBox = DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
            txtBox.Text = rowvm.Rolldown
        end if

    End If

End sub
```

Comment: You need to rebuild the DataSource and Bind it to your Repeater again after DB Update. Only Calling DataBind() method won't do anything.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to know for sure.

Comment: I requery the data and have examined the view model being sent back the page and it contains the proper data.